# When promoting a hero, how to increase his ability's rank?

Tags: the-banner-saga

Each hero has an ability with 3 ranks.

[image: Hero's ability]

During the promotion phase, you can increase stats by clicking it (on the right side of the screen), but I can't find how to increase the said ability: clicking its icon only opens its description.

[image: Hero's promotion screen]

Is it normal?  Is there anything special to do in order to inscrease the ability?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ability rank will raise itself when going up further levels - first ability rank on level 1, second on level 3 and third on level 5. You don't need to invest character points for the ability rank to rise.